# Multiple meta key and meta value search

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am working on client project and stumped upon multiple meta_key, meta value search.

My db structure is like that

```
clinics                   clinics_meta
=======                   =============
id   name                id fk_clinic_id   meta_key   meta_value
1    dental               1   1             city       london
2    heart                2   1             country    england
                          3   2             city       manchester
                          4   2             country    london
```

I want to get clinic with `city = london` and `country = england`

I tried like this

```
SELECT distinct(clinics.id) FROM clinics, clinic_meta
WHERE clinics.id = clinic_meta.fkClinicId
AND  (clinic_meta.metaKey = 'clinicCountry' AND clinic_meta.metaValue like '%england%')
AND  (clinic_meta.metaKey = 'clinicCity' AND clinic_meta.metaValue like '%london%')
```

Please dont conside syntax error but the logic.

this code does not return `clinic name/id`,

but instead of using two filter city,country

If I use only one filter it does return clinic name.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    select cl.* from clinics cl
     inner join 
     clinics_meta cm1 
     on cl.id=cm.clinic_id
     inner join 
     clinics_meta cm2
     on cm1.clinic_id=cm2.clinic_id
     where cm1.meta_key='Country' and cm1.meta_value='England' 
     and cm1.meta_key='City' and cm2.meta_value='London'
    group by t1.id;
```

Comment: Thank you Long Dog,
Do i have to increase number on joins if number of metakey value filters increases?

Comment: No problem, looks like it, yes...  I'd add an index to clinics_meta if there isn't one:
alter table clinic_meta add key (meta_key,meta_value);
I assume that there are already keys on clinics_meta.clinic_id and clinic.id?